# app store - where to download the report of app downloads?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

[image]

Ok, in itunesconnect, it says Preview or download your daily and weekly sales information here.

but when I click in, I only can preview on the chart? How can I download?

if I want to count the total number of downloads for my app, I have to create my own excel and fill in the number everyday myself?

thanks

Comment: This question would be better suited for [the App Stores proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) on Area 51.

Comment: Actually, while still off topic, this is a great question!

Comment: It's a borderline question; while "App Stores" is in beta, this is probably the best (least worst) place for it.

Comment: lol i didn't know app stores proposal site, well, for me, stackoverflow only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Login to iTunes Connect
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/

2) Go to Sales and Trends

3) Click the Sales tab

4) Select the day with the pop-up, (or the week if you want a weekly report)

5) Click "Sales Report" on the right to download the report

6) Repeat as necessary

Comment: Direct link (need login first): https://reportingitc2.apple.com/reports.html